# Подсчитать сумму чисел в файле записанных через пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Решил сделать через добавление в список, и затем форматнуть, и вывести сумму.

Но что-то пошло не так!?

```
number = []
f = open('data_2.txt' ,'r')
file = f.readlines()
for i in file:
    number.append([int(x) for x in i.split()])
    numbers_ = ''.join(map(str,number))
    print((numbers_))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заметки на полях:

- файл открыт и не закрыт. На максимальную скорость не влияет, но если в будущем вы будете открывать много файлов, операционная система откажет вам в доступе из-за нехватки ресурсов;
- `readlines` почти никогда не нужен;
- в коде нет сложения чисел. Как тогда вычислить сумму?

Первое решение. Файл обрабатывается последовательно: сумма будет посчитана даже если файл не лезет в оперативную память:

```
with open('data_2.txt') as f:       # закроет файл за собой
    s = 0
    for line in f:                  # перебирает строки в файле
        for word in line.split():   # перебирает слова в строке
            s += int(word)          # накапливает сумму
print(s)
```

Второе решение. Смешивать перебор чисел из файла и суммирование - плохо. Питон позволяет их разделить. И снова файл не загружается в память целиком:

```
def ints(f):                      # вход - файл, выход - последовательность чисел
    for line in f:                # строки из файла
        for word in line.split(): # слова из строк
            yield int(word)       # волшебство


with open('data_2.txt') as f:
    print(sum(ints(f)))           # sum суммирует последовательность
```

Третье решение. Проход по файлу всё ещё смешан с функциональностью: слова превращаются в числа. Разделим:

```
def words(f):                      # вход - файл, выход - последовательность слов
    for line in f:                 # строки из файла
        for word in line.split():  # слова из строк
            yield word             # волшебство


with open('data_2.txt') as f:
    print(sum(map(int, words(f)))) # map переводит слова в числа
                                   # sum суммирует
```

Четвёртое решение. Конструкция `for ...: yield ...` упрощается до `yield from ...`:

```
def words(f):                   # вход - файл, выход - последовательность слов
    for line in f:              # строки из файла
        yield from line.split() # слова из строк и волшебство
```

Пятое решение. `words` - функция-генератор. Можно сделать её обычной функцией, которая вернёт выражение-генератор. Ещё раз напомню, что генераторы не читают файл целиком в память. По прежнему в памяти только одна последняя прочитанная строка:

```
def words(f):
    return (word for line in f for word in line.split())
```

Шестое решение. Раз всё свелось к выражению генератору, то и функция не нужна:

```
with open('data_2.txt') as f:
    print(sum(map(int, (word for line in f for word in line.split()))))
```

Седьмое решение. `map` не нужен, получается даже короче:

```
with open('data_2.txt') as f:
    print(sum(int(word) for line in f for word in line.split()))
```

Восьмое решение. Всё по частям: отдельно читаются слова, отдельно переводятся в числа, отдельно суммируются:

```
def words(f):                   # функция-генератор
    for line in f:
        yield from line.split()


def ints(f):                    # обычная функция, возвращающая генератор
    return map(int, words(f))


with open('data_2.txt') as f:
    # напечатай(сумму(целых(из файла)))
    print(sum(ints(f)))
```

Восемь разных решений - одна суть: файл не читается в память целиком, генераторы обрабатывают данные по мере поступления.

Comment: Благодарю за детальный и развернутый ответ !

Answer (score 5):

Я надеюсь это то что было нужно:

```
with open('data_2.txt', 'r') as file:
    result = 0
    for line in file:
        result += sum(list(map(int, line.split())))
```

Comment: Можно и одним списковым включением, но тоже неплохо

Comment: `sum(list(map(...)))` ->  `sum(map(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

Я немного улучшил вариант Exemplles, получился однострочник.

```py
result = sum([sum(list(map(int, line.split()))) for line in open('data_2.txt', 'r')])
```

Необязательно закрывать файл, если он не помещен в переменную. Как только ссылки на объект перестают существовать, он очищается сборщиком мусора. А значит по окончании этого однострочника файл закроется

Comment: И все-таки, это не совсем правильно, CPython, конечно, сам удалит ссылки на файл сборщиком мусора, вследствие чего файл закроется, но это именно детали реализации CPython, стандарт языка на это явно никаких гарантий не дает, а потому лучше делать явно, через with

Comment: @Павел, файл будет оставаться открытым пока выражение `for ... in ...` его использует. Здесь нет ошибки. Недостаток в том что не известно как скоро после вычисления файл будет закрыт. `with` гарантирует закрытие "не слишком поздно". Этот код вполне рабочий.

Comment: `sum([...])` -> `sum(...)`, `sum(list(...))` -> `sum(...)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я согласен, что он рабочий в `CPython`, но здесь используется "скрытая" логика именно реализации самого интерпретатора, нигде, в документации языка, не сказано, что файл будет закрываться автоматически, если на него больше нет ссылок, если мы возьмем какую-то другую реализацию `Python`, то там это поведение уже может быть совсем другим. И, в целом - явное, лучше чем неявное.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простой вариант решения - использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
```